# Probability of a real random uniform distributed number is picked $>t$ times before all other possible numbers have been picked at least once?

Tags: probability, random, binomial-distribution, coupon-collector

Given a real random number generator with uniform distribution of values between $1$ and $N$. The random number series ends if all values between $1$ and $N$ have been picked at least once.
How high is the chance that any of those numbers have been picked $t$ or more times? $(t>1)$

### Solving attempt:

(approximation)
How many numbers needed to get all values? $=T$
->[Coupon collector's problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupon_collector's_problem)

$$E(T) = N \cdot H_N = N \log N + \gamma N + \frac{1}{2} + O(1/N)$$
$$\gamma \approx 0.5772156649$$

Number of values which are duplicates $D$: $$D=E(T)-N$$

Chance of $t$ or more repetitions of one number (binomial distribution):

$$p_1(>=t) = \sum_{k=t}^D \binom{D}{k}\frac{1}{N^k}(1-\frac{1}{N})^{D-k}$$

...but this is only for one number. Any idea how to compute the probability of all numbers?
Or some alternative way of solving this?

### Edit: Findings so far

from antkam:
$$T-1 > (t-1)\cdot (N-1)$$
with this also
$$t >= \frac{T-1}{N-1}$$

Comment: Just a few observations: If $T > (t-1)(n-1)$ then it is certain that some number has been picked $t$ or more times.  So if $E[T] > (t-1)(n-1)$ my gut feel would be that the probability is close to $1$, and my wild guess is if $E[T] > $ something like $\frac12 (t-1)(n-1)$ the probability would still be quite high already.  So if you have specific $t, n$ in mind they might be in this regime.  I have no idea how to solve this exactly and in full generality though.  Perhaps a small Monte Carlo simulation?

Comment: @antkam why $-1$ in $T>(t-1)(n-1)$? E.g. If $n=(N)=11$ and $t=3$ the result of this equation would be $T>20$. Now there can be the case all numbers $1..N$ only two times, that would be $22$ which is larger than $20$ but still no $t>=3$. It should be $T>(t-1)(n)$, or?

Comment: Sorry, I had a minor mistake.  $T$ is the moment when the last number appears, so among the first $T-1$ "dicerolls" are the other $n-1$ numbers.  So we really need $T-1 > (t-1)(n-1)$.  In your example, if $T-1 > 20$ then you cannot have $10$ number each appearing only twice among the first $T-1 \ge 21$ "dicerolls".  Anyway, it is $n-1$ and not $n$ because you are applying pigeonhole to the other $n-1$ numbers, i.e. all except the last-appearing one (which is guaranteed to have appeared only once, at $T$).

Comment: I suspect simulation may not be too difficult.  For example with $n=100$, simulation suggested $t$ has a mean of about $11.66$ and standard deviation about $2.37$, with $P(t \ge 10) \approx 0.828$ and $P(t \ge 15) \approx 0.116$, though I would not trust any of those final decimal places

Comment: Let $X_n\stackrel{\mathrm{i.i.d.}}\sim\mathrm{Unif}\{1,2,\ldots,N\}$ and $\tau_i = \inf\{n>0: X_n = i\}$ for $i=1,2,\ldots N$. Set $\tau = \bigvee_{i=1}^N \tau_i$. The probability we seek is
$$
\mathbb P\left(\bigcup_{i=1}^N \left\{\sum_{j=1}^\tau \mathsf 1_{\{X_j=i\}} \geqslant t\right\} \right).
$$
I highly doubt there is a simple closed form.